# Preg_split, unicode - длина слов

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Разбиваю строку на массив из слов, но нужно ограничить мин. длину слов, которые будут попадать в массив, делаю, так:

```
$request_uri = preg_split('/\P{L}{3,}+/u', $request_uri);
```

в обычном режиме работает:

```
$request_uri = preg_split('/\P{L}+/u', $request_uri);
```

Как можно задать длину в мин. 3 символа?

Спасибо

**Обновление**

Извиняюсь, при написание поста, случайно не ту скобку поставил.

по стандарту /\P{L}+/u, выдает

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => palm )
```

при '/\P{L}{3,}/u', выдает

```
Array ( [0] => 'palm )
```

а нужно, чтобы во втором варианте, не было спец. символов, почему они появляются?

Comment: Вы закрывающую скобку не перепутали? Да и плюс после {3,} может являться синтаксической ошибкой.

Comment: @aliokero, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$a = preg_match_all('/[\w]{3,}+/u',$url, $ar1);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Разбиваю строку на массив из слов

[[@aliokero](/users/24240/aliokero)](/users/24240/aliokero), как я понимаю, Вы хотите найти все слова в тексте и поместить их в массив? Если это так, то `preg_split` неверное решение.

**Обновление**

Может быть, поможет достигнуть желаемого результата:

```
preg_match_all( "/\\b\\p{L}{3,}+\\b/", $text, $result );
```

?

Comment: Да, Вы верно поняли. Explode не подойдет, т.к. шаблона нет, как такового и разделителем выступают любые символы кроме букв и цифр. preg_split справляется с задачей, но выводит союзы и предлоги, поэтому, нужно ограничить заполнение массива словами от 3-х знаков.

Answer (score 0):

`preg_match_all()` и выделить все слова (задать минимальную длину в регулярке), либо `preg_split()` разбить по разделителю, а короткие слова выкинуть из уже полученного массива